# Button click not firing in modal window (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button in a modal window:

```
<button id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-link">Send the invitation</button>
```

I'm trying to capture the click:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( "GO" ); 
});
```

I've read that button clicks get swallowed in modal windows and that, to prevent that, use event.preventDefault(). But that's not working. I can't capture the click event of this button.

What else am I missing?

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Open console and try triggering the event .. Check if it works.. If it works then it might be a `z-index` issue

Comment: Open up your console and see if there are any Javascript errors. This seems to work fine to me.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle that works - http://jsfiddle.net/GqD4f/8/ /edit Your approach should work, here is a jsfiddle that works - http://jsfiddle.net/CR3bM/1/ - Are you not putting your event handler in DOM ready?

Comment: Yes, I'm not putting my event handler in DOM ready. I forgot that part. However, I did try it in my event handler for "shown" for the modal window and that didn't work.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this -

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit_btn", function(event){
    alert( "GO" ); 
});
```

Or this -

```
$(document).delegate("#submit_btn", "click", function(event){
    alert( "GO" ); 
});
```

If you are using an older version of jQuery you may have to use the live method instead.

Live method (use this only if you have to)

```
$("#submit_btn").live("click", function(event){
    alert( "GO" ); 
});
```

I'm fairly certain that one of these 3 methods above will solve your issue.  The reason your event handler doesn't work is because your submit_btn element doesn't exist at the time your event handler is evaluated.  The above 3 handlers I gave you will work on a submit_btn element that exists now and **in the future**.

/edit

Here is a jsfiddle that works - http://jsfiddle.net/GqD4f/8/

/another edit

I made a jsfiddle using the approach you had in your post and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/CR3bM/1/

Are you not putting your event handler in DOM ready?

Comment: Yes live is deprecated from v1.7.x onward and removed in v1.9.  If he is using a version before 1.4.2 he will need to use live.  It also has slower performance than using delegate or on method - http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.9.1. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: And no, I wasn't putting the event handler in DOM ready. My poor decision there.

Comment: why under $(document) ?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit_btn", function(event){
    alert("GO"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did with class(`.copy-text`).

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.copy-text', function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="someid" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">    
      <ul class="list-group"> 
        <li class="list-group-item copy-text">Some text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now.

For some reason if you wrap

```
  $(document).on("click","span.editComment",function(event) {
```

within one of these:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

Then it doesn't catch the click for some weird reason. Just remove the surrounding document ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {}
```

And your code should work!