# Button click not firing in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-events, bootstrap-5

I'm using jQuery v3.6.0 and Bootstrap v5.0.2.  I have a dynamically generated modal which has buttons.  When the modal pops up, none of the buttons work and I cannot figure out why.

Here's what I have tried:

```
$('#btnStayLoggedIn').click(function() {...});
$('#btnStayLoggedIn').on('click', function() {...});
$('#btnStayLoggedIn').delegate('click', function() {...});
$('#btnStayLoggedIn').live('click', function() {...});
```

Basically, I have tried [everything in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455906/button-click-not-firing-in-modal-window-bootstrap).  There are no errors in the console or anything.  It just will not fire.  Note: in jQuery 3.6.0, using live gives an error...

Here's the code for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btnStayLoggedIn">Stay Logged In</button>
```

And here's the code for the handler:

```
// Called if the user clicks the Stay Logged In button.
$("#btnStayLoggedIn").delegate('click', function() {
    console.log("execute 1"); 
    if (typeof logoutTimer === 'object') {
        console.log("execute 2"); 
        logoutTimer.stayLoggedIn();
    }
});
```

The eventual handler is inside an object that has everything for the dialog that pops up when the timer expires.  On top of that, when I try to manually trigger the handler in the console, that doesn't work either.  I'm using this in the console:

```
$('#btnStayLoggedIn').click();
```

It just gives me some object to look at in the console:

```
jQuery.fn.init [button#btnLogout.btn.btn-default]
```

What I did find though, is that if I manually add an event handler to the button, then it will work:

```
btn1Obj = document.createElement("button");
btn1Obj.classList.add("btn", "btn-default");
btn1Obj.setAttribute("id", "btnStayLoggedIn");
btn1Obj.innerText = "Stay Logged In";
btn1Obj.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.stayLoggedIn();
}.bind(this));
```

So why is this a problem with jQuery?

Comment: try a delegate event listener `$('body').on('click', ''#btnStayLoggedIn',  function() {...});`

Comment: That didn't work either.  I'm going to stick with the addEventListener method above.  That I know does work.